# Why did all div appear under each other?

Tags: html, css

I am not asking this because it's a problem for me, actually, that's exactly how I wanted to display the divs, but I didn't know they would appear below each other. Why is that? I only gave them width and height, I didn't position them.
I thought they would appear on each other at the same position

```
<div class="D1">

</div>
<div class="D2">

</div>

<div class="D3">

</div>

<div class="D4">

</div>

.D1,.D2,.D3,.D4{ 
border:1px solid;
border-color:red;
width:500px;
height:200px;
}
/*  OR 
div{
border:1px solid;
border-color:red;
width:500px;
height:200px;
}
*/
```

Sorry for this probably dumb question, but I'm just curious :D

Comment: Because that's their natural behavior as a "block" element ...

Comment: `I thought they would appear on each other at the same position` --> why you thought this ?

Comment: Use `display: inline-block` for what you thought

Comment: First read about differences between inline and block level elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the expected behavior.

`div` by default are `block` elements which means that they always start on a new line and take up the full width available.

If you want elements to be on the same line and to only take up as much width as necessary, you must use `inline` elements, such as `span`.

Find [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp) a complete reference

Comment: this is not the issue .. he want them `on each other at the same position` ! i guess we won't expect this behavior too

Comment: This explains why they appear below each other so it answers the question "Why is that?".

Comment: well, it's trivial for me as there is nothing to explain, and your first sentence is enough ... but if we was asking why they are not next to each other, this should be the answer (difference between block and inline) ... but he's thinking why they are not ON EACH OTHER so the question is why he's expecting such behavior which is not logical at all

Answer (score 0):

By default, the flow of the page will display your divs elements (which are blocks) one below another as you have seen.

If you want to override this behaviour you could set a

```
position: absolute;
```

property to your divs so they can be placed wherever you want regardless of the position of other elements. For example you may want to set all your divs at the top left corner by doing:

```
div {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

By default display property is block for div.Change it to inline to display in one line.

Answer (score -2):

If you use `float: left;` in css, the problem will be solved. Because div element is a block level element.